# how to make a python 3 program to search google?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making an AI program using python 3 I want to add google search feature in it please can anyone help me with it. 
If a user as my program "search google ..." the program will open chrome and search google the question and also it will read two lines of the search.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options that I can think of:

1. Google provides a [RESTful search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview), which will return the
   search result as a JSON object you can parse. This will require you
   to handle a network error if the program cannot connect to the
   internet. You can only get 100 queries a day before billing is
   required.
2. It also sounds as though you could just open up the appropriate web
   page for the user with their preferred browser. All you need to do
   is open the webpage:

   > https://www.google.com/search?q=FOO+BAR

   Where 'FOO+BAR' is your search query, delimited with plus signs. You can combine this with the Python webbrowser module to open the page.

   ```
   import webbrowser

   webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=FOO+BAR')
   ```

Hope that helps.